# Gradle fastest task for compilation check

Tags: android, gradle

Whick gradle task is the fastest to check whether the code passes compilation without any syntax error on Android project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the output of the command

```
./gradlew tasks --all
```

executed in a directory containing a small Android project, I'd suggest that your best bet is either the command

```
./gradlew compileReleaseSources
```

or the command

```
./gradlew compileReleaseJava
```

Here's the full list of tasks that `compileReleaseSources` depends on for my project (might vary slightly for your own):

```
app:compileReleaseSources
    app:checkReleaseManifest
    app:compileReleaseAidl
    app:compileReleaseJava
    app:compileReleaseNdk
    app:compileReleaseRenderscript
    app:generateReleaseAssets
    app:generateReleaseBuildConfig
    app:generateReleaseResValues
    app:generateReleaseResources
    app:generateReleaseSources
    app:mergeReleaseAssets
    app:mergeReleaseResources
    app:preBuild
    app:preDebugBuild
    app:preReleaseBuild
    app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72210Library - Prepare com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.0
    app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42210Library - Prepare com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.0
    app:prepareReleaseDependencies
    app:processReleaseManifest
    app:processReleaseResources
```

Note that this includes the Java compilation step, as well as the compilation of other code sources and various resource processing. Depending on your exact needs, calling `compileReleaseJava` instead of `compileReleaseSources` may be enough and will be faster. (Unfortunately, I don't know of a way to view Gradle task dependencies in a tree-like structure, so it's not clear to me exactly how much faster the `compileReleaseJava` task would be).

If you also want to check that test code compiles, you'd need to add an analogous command: e.g. `compileDebugTestSources`.

Comment: Thanks man!The idea behind this is to do the check on a CI server for very intensive development and I think compileReleaseSources is it.